# Script Error Couldn't find module: hyperloop/ for architecture: x86_64

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

When trying to use Appcelerator Hyperloop and include a third party library i always get this error tried four different library.

The docs state add the podfile.

pod "BAFluidView"

https://github.com/antiguab/BAFluidView

Run pod install and it installs correctly.

but when trying to include it into my project with.

```
// Require in 3rd Party Native Classes
    var BAFluidView = require('BAFluidView/BAFluidView');
    var test = new BAFluidView();
```

Just get the following error.

> Script Error Couldn't find module: hyperloop/bafluidview/bafluidview
>   for architecture: x86_64

Comment: were u able to find any solution for this  ?

Comment: @Ekra nope, i gave up.